# Getting started with IIS

Tags: iis

I am new to .NET development, and would like to get a handle on IIS, what resources do people think are the best?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely start at the official learning IIS site: [Learn.IIS.net](http://learn.iis.net/)

There's a [Getting Started](http://www.iis.net/getstarted) section where you can pick and choose what you want to focus on.

The first few bullets show us that the content is focused on:

- planning your IIS7 architecture
- installing and configuring IIS7
- deploying sites
- managing + maintaining IIS

There are blogs there from the IIS team and other Microsofties. Books are on showcase, lots of downloads, and a whole set of forums.